# How to fix Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, file, error-handling, read.csv

In this code I have tried to use a for loop for id values and some if if else statements because the files were in "001.csv", form and "010" form so I made this code. The plan was to store a character vector and then read it using `read.csv`.

I used `getwd()` function to get the working directory and then `setwd` to set it as the same directory but it still didn't work. So basically breaking the loop in 1's and 10s I tried to form this function, the main issue is with reading this file.

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

is what it is showing to me. I use Windows 10 and Rstudio.

```
pollutmean <- function(pollutant="sulfate", id=1:332) {
  for (i in id) {
    if (i < 10) {
      x <- i
      char <- as.character(x)
      a <- paste("C:/Users/ksart/Desktop/Specdata/Specdata/00", char, ".csv",
                 sep="")  # this is where i m trying to read in the values
      temp1 <- read.csv(a)
      data_1 <- rbind.data.frame(data_1, temp1)
      data_1
    }      
    else if (10 <= i && i < 100 ) {  # for 10s files
      y <- i
      char1 <- as.character(y)
      b <- paste("C:/Users/ksart/Desktop/Specdata/Specdata/0", char1, ".csv",
                 sep="")
```

Comment: Why do you have a "." before the "C:/" in your path? Does it work if you remove this?

Comment: char1<-as.character(14) 
                                   b<-paste("0",char1,".csv",sep="")
temp22<-read.csv(file=b,header = TRUE)                                                               
                                                                                                                                  
                                   this seems to work if i run this piece separately

Comment: the . wont make a change, it still shows the same error

Comment: i m sure the loop works fine because when i added print(a) in the first loop it shows "001.csv"

Comment: The path is correct? I'm suspicious about the Specdata/Specdata part.

Comment: Some suggestions to simplify the code above (can't format code in a comment). Also corrected the problem with `rbind.data.frame`. https://pastebin.com/nia3tESM

Comment: thank alot !! you are amazing

Comment: the code worked fine. The path was correct i made two Specdata folders9one inside another.